# The question asks to check a list against a dictionary and add a * before items on the list that do not appear in the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to add a (*) to every item in the list that is not found in the dictionary.
Here is what I currently have:

```
dictionary = {'a', 'b', 'd'}
words = ['d', 'c', 'x', 'a']
for i in words:
    if i not in dictionary:
        words[i] = '*' + words[i]
```

I get the error:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

From what I understand, that means it can't go through the for loop because it is not numbers, but I don't understand how to fix it. I don't even know what to look up :(

I'm new to python so be gentle.

Answer (score 3):

First, your `dictionary` variable is actually a `set`, second, you can use `range` and `len` to loop over indices rather than values:

```
dictionary = {'a', 'b', 'd'} # actually a set
words = ['d', 'c', 'x', 'a']

for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i] not in dictionary:
        words[i] = '*' + words[i]

print(words)
```

Output:

```
['d', '*c', '*x', 'a']
```

Alternatively, you can use `enumerate`, which will give you both the indices and the values without having to index the `list` manually to get the values:

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if word not in dictionary:
        words[i] = '*' + word
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that doesn't need the index directly is to replace `words` list directly with list comprehension, as

```
dictionary = {'a', 'b', 'd'} # actually a set
words = ['d', 'c', 'x', 'a']

words = [w if w in dictionary else '*'+w for w in words]

print(words)
```

with output

```
['d', '*c', '*x', 'a']
```

Comment: this is the recommended approach, but this is really giving away too much on an obvious homework question

Answer (score -1):

The natural way to get the results you want in Python is to create a *new* list with the desired values, which we can easily do via a list comprehension.

```
to_mark = {'a', 'b', 'd'} # mark words that are in this set.
words = ['d', 'c', 'x', 'a']

words = ['*' + w if w in to_mark else w for w in words]
```

Two concepts are introduced here: the list comprehension, which lets us describe one list in terms of an existing one, and the conditional expression (`'*' + w if w in to_mark else w`). We build a new list by taking each of the words (named `w` for reference) and evaluating the expression to get each new item. When `w` is `in to_mark`, we produce `'*' + w`; `else` we produce the original `w`.